# Orientation from wheel based odometry vs IMU

Tags: ros, imu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have run some tests using the jackal and ros indigo.
I collected the "x,y,z,w" values for the orientation from the wheel based odometry. These are quaternion representations of the orientation of the jackal.

Similar values are printed for the IMU as well.
Here are some values which I logged:

```
//odometry orientation
[ INFO] [1524638957.013930930]:robotorn:x,y,z,w=0.000000,0.000000,0.037674,0.999290 
 
 //Imu orientation
[ INFO] [1524638957.013949804]:robotimu:x,y,z=0.000690,-0.000165,-0.987262
```

Why are the IMU values negative as compared to those of the odometry? Which should we consider while making our calculations?

Regards,
rsmitha.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289720/orientation-from-wheel-based-odometry-vs-imu/) by [rsmitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/28985/rsmitha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2018-04-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-04-26**:
You are comparing the values between a quaternion and euler angles ?

**Comment by [rsmitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/28985/rsmitha/) on 2018-04-26**:
Hi @Delb, I am comparing quaternions for odometry and imu. I did not capture the'w' value for the imu as I forgot to add it to the ROS INFO list.

**Comment by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) on 2018-04-26**:
I find quaternions pretty hard to compare without straight up plotting / drawing them or converting to euler angles. Which one you should use will depend on your application requirements & the quality of the IMU you're using (e.g., is it the onboard IMU?).

**Comment by [rsmitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/28985/rsmitha/) on 2018-04-26**:
Hi.@stevejp, I am using the onboard imu.

**Comment by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) on 2018-04-26**:
and what is your application / goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's because of how quaternions are maid, [here](http://quaternions.online/) is a little tool to see the evolution of the values of Euler angles and quaternion, you could see that (in Euler angles) for x=y=z=0 you can either have the w=1 or -1 (yet it's the same orientation).

For your calculations you should consider the most precise one. Odometry can be wrong if your robot drift, but usually you combine the wheel based odometry and the IMU to have the best value.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rsmitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/28985/rsmitha/) on 2018-04-26**:
Hi @Delb, thanks for the visualisation link. Its great. If I have just the x,y,z values for the imu orientation and I wish to calculate the angle, would it be possible to do so without the 'w'? This is so I can plot orintation change for imu values. Regards, rsmitha.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-04-26**:
Why don't you have the w ? If the IMU generates a quaternion then you can directly use the functions from the answers of [#q50113](https://answers.ros.org/question/50113/transform-quaternion/)